# 403 Forbidden error with Django and mod_wsgi

Tags: python, django, apache2, mod-wsgi

I created Django project in home directory so it is in home directory.

**Setup**

```
Django Verison  : 1.5.1
Python Version  : 2.7.5
mod_wsgi Version: 3.4
Home Directory  : /home/aettool
```

**Contents of `/home/aettool/aet/apache/django.wsgi`**

```
import os
import sys
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'aet.settings'

import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

**Contect of `httpd.conf`**

```
WSGIScriptAlias / /home/aettool/aet/apache/django.wsgi

<Directory /home/aettool/aet/apache>
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Directory>
```

**Error in `error_log`**

```
[Sun Jul 21 02:01:30.923364 2013] [authz_core:error] [pid 21540:tid 1193011520] [client 10.20.17.184:51340] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /home/aettool/aet/apache/django.wsgi
```

**Contents of `urls.py`**

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

Permissions of `/home/aettool/aet : 775`

Permissions of `/home/aettool/aet/apache : 755`

Permissions of `django.wsgi file : 664`

I am getting error on browser `403 Forbidden` `You don't have permission to access / on this server.`

Please help me out with the configuration .

**EDIT**

For now I am moving forward by changing

```
<Directory />
    AllowOverride none
    Require all denied
</Directory>
```

to

```
<Directory />
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

So,this has definitely something to do with `httpd.conf` file configuration,but my worry is that I only added 5 lines in that file and not able to figure out what's wrong .

Comment: Please show us your `urls.py`

Comment: added in the question

Comment: Dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4807176/apache-mod-wsgi-error-forbidden-you-dont-have-permission-to-access-on-this-s?rq=1

Comment: Also, use gunicorn. Its not only faster but easier to set up. If you have the ability of using gunicorn, then please do.

Comment: No,its different.Though both questions are similar.Solution there is is not applicable here.I have permissions of files right.Though I am placing the wsgi file in the same place as the project but that still should not give the error that I am getting.

Comment: Ignore my answer. Changing my `httpd.conf` right now after reading the dupe question.

Comment: did you check the rights of /home and /home/aettool too ?

Comment: For another potential cause of this error, see this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3749331/django-with-mod-wsgi-returns-403-error

Answer (score 39):

Apparently this is an issue that is related to Apache 2.4 and older versions.
You need to replace in your apache configuration:

```
Allow from all
```

with

```
Require all granted
```

in the `<Files wsgi.py>` section

Answer (score 16):

You can use the following:

```
<Directory /home/aettool/aet/apache>
  <IfVersion < 2.3 >
   Order allow,deny
   Allow from all
  </IfVersion>
  <IfVersion >= 2.3>
   Require all granted
  </IfVersion>
</Directory>
```

Comment: On old apache versions it will be needed to enable the "version" mod with ```sudo a2enmod version```

Answer (score 4):

This has been reported in Django ticket 19319:

https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/19319

Your Apache config now needs the following for your file `wsgi.py`.

```
<Directory /path/to/your/wsgi-script>
<Files wsgi.py>
  Order deny,allow
  Allow from all
  Require all granted
</Files>
</Directory>
```

Comment: This worked, but with <Directory /path/to/parent/directory> not to wsgi-script

Answer (score 3):

There is one other gotcha:

Check your httpd.conf file for the following configuration:

```
<IfModule mime_module>
      AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .pl .py
</IfModule>
```

This will cause the error.

.py MUST NOT be configured as a CGI script

Comment: This was it for me. Thanks.

Comment: DUDE, U SAVE MY LIFE. first of all the tutorial makes me add .py in those lines.. and it cause error. i been burn out 2 days to solve this issue. thank you so much man

Answer (score -1):

Linux systems usually don't allow other users to read inside the home directory, and as Apache runs as root, mod_wsgi will not be able to access the inside of the home directory. 
Try:

```
sudo chmod 755 /home/<username>
```

Comment: This is generally a really bad idea, please use the other solutions instead!