# apache2 and mod wsgi : Target WSGI script cannot be loaded as Python module

Tags: python, linux, apache2, mod-wsgi, wsgi

I am trying to install mod_wsgi on apache2, on ubuntu.
So I install libapache2-mod-wsgi package, I activate him with a2enmod.

I got a web site (languageAnalyz), that I am trying to use with mod_wsgi.
When I call localhost/languageAnalyz, I got an error 500.

In apache2 log, I can see this :

```
[Sun Aug 25 11:28:21 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] mod_wsgi (pid=4993): Target WSGI script '/var/www/languageAnalyz/test-wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Sun Aug 25 11:28:21 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] mod_wsgi (pid=4993): SystemExit exception raised by WSGI script '/var/www/languageAnalyz/test-wsgi.py' ignored.
[Sun Aug 25 11:28:21 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Sun Aug 25 11:28:21 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "/var/www/languageAnalyz/test-wsgi.py", line 10, in <module>
[Sun Aug 25 11:28:21 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     WSGIServer(app).run()
[Sun Aug 25 11:28:21 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flup/server/fcgi.py", line 112, in run
[Sun Aug 25 11:28:21 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     sock = self._setupSocket()
[Sun Aug 25 11:28:21 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flup/server/fcgi_base.py", line 997, in _setupSocket
[Sun Aug 25 11:28:21 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     req.run()
[Sun Aug 25 11:28:21 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flup/server/fcgi_base.py", line 572, in run
[Sun Aug 25 11:28:21 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     self._end(appStatus, protocolStatus)
[Sun Aug 25 11:28:21 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flup/server/fcgi_base.py", line 601, in _end
[Sun Aug 25 11:28:21 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     sys.exit(appStatus)
[Sun Aug 25 11:28:21 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] SystemExit: 0
```

I googled this error, and I find lot of solutions (most of the times for Django project).
What I undsertand, is that I need to create a `__init__.py` file.
What I did, here is my `__init__.py` file :

```
__all__ = ['app','get_size_dir','get_nbrf_dir','getStats'] #name of my functions
import index # my three python files
import analyz
import test-wsgi
```

In the `__all__` list, this is the name of the functions in the three files.
I am just trying to launch test-wsgi.py, and get the same error 500.

Here is my test-wsgi.py file :

```
import os,sys
sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(__file__))
from cgi import escape,parse_qs
from flup.server.fcgi import WSGIServer
def app(environ, start_response):
  start_response('200 OK',[('Content-Type','text/plain; charset=utf-8')])
   yield "hello world!"
WSGIServer(app).run()
```

So what's wrong ?
Thank you,

Edit :
here is my apache2 conf :

```
WSGIPythonPath /var/www/languageAnalyz
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ...
  <Directory /var/www/languageAnalyz/>
    Options +Indexes ExecCGI FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    DirectoryIndex index.py
    SetHandler wsgi-script
  </Directory>
  ...
</VirtualHost>
```

Edit_bis :
So I try to do as I read on django doc.
I change my apache2 conf to :

```
WSGIPythonPath /var/www/languageAnalyz
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ...
   WSGIScriptAlias /IPA /var/www/languageAnalyz/testwsgi.py
    <Directory /var/www/languageAnalyz/>
            Options +Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride None
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
            DirectoryIndex testwsgi.py
    </Directory>

  ...
</VirtualHost>
```

I restart apache2, and I got the same error, and one more before :

```
[Sun Aug 25 12:47:18 2013] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Sun Aug 25 12:47:19 2013] [notice] FastCGI: wrapper mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/lib/apache2/suexec)
[Sun Aug 25 12:47:19 2013] [notice] FastCGI: process manager initialized (pid 7879)
[Sun Aug 25 12:47:19 2013] [notice] mod_python: Creating 8 session mutexes based on 150 max processes and 0 max threads.
[Sun Aug 25 12:47:19 2013] [notice] mod_python: using mutex_directory /tmp
[Sun Aug 25 12:47:19 2013] [warn] mod_wsgi: Compiled for Python/2.7.3.
[Sun Aug 25 12:47:19 2013] [warn] mod_wsgi: Runtime using Python/2.7.4.
[Sun Aug 25 12:47:19 2013] [notice] Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) mod_fastcgi/mod_fastcgi-SNAP-0910052141 PHP/5.4.9-4ubuntu2.2 mod_python/3.3.1 Python/2.7.4 mod_ruby/1.2.6 Ruby/1.8.7(2012-02-08) mod_wsgi/3.4 configured$
[Sun Aug 25 12:47:19 2013] [error] WSGIServer: missing FastCGI param REQUEST_METHOD required by WSGI!
[Sun Aug 25 12:47:19 2013] [error] WSGIServer: missing FastCGI param SERVER_NAME required by WSGI!
[Sun Aug 25 12:47:19 2013] [error] WSGIServer: missing FastCGI param SERVER_PORT required by WSGI!
[Sun Aug 25 12:47:19 2013] [error] WSGIServer: missing FastCGI param SERVER_PROTOCOL required by WSGI!
[Sun Aug 25 12:47:19 2013] [error] Status: 200 OK\r
[Sun Aug 25 12:47:19 2013] [error] Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8\r
[Sun Aug 25 12:47:19 2013] [error] \r
[Sun Aug 25 12:47:19 2013] [error] hello world!
[Sun Aug 25 12:47:19 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] mod_wsgi (pid=7884): Target WSGI script '/var/www/languageAnalyz/testwsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Sun Aug 25 12:47:19 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] mod_wsgi (pid=7884): SystemExit exception raised by WSGI script '/var/www/languageAnalyz/testwsgi.py' ignored.
[Sun Aug 25 12:47:19 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Sun Aug 25 12:47:19 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "/var/www/languageAnalyz/testwsgi.py", line 10, in <module>
[Sun Aug 25 12:47:19 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     WSGIServer(app).run()
[Sun Aug 25 12:47:19 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flup/server/fcgi.py", line 112, in run
[Sun Aug 25 12:47:19 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     sock = self._setupSocket()
[Sun Aug 25 12:47:19 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flup/server/fcgi_base.py", line 997, in _setupSocket
[Sun Aug 25 12:47:19 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     req.run()
[Sun Aug 25 12:47:19 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flup/server/fcgi_base.py", line 572, in run
[Sun Aug 25 12:47:19 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     self._end(appStatus, protocolStatus)
[Sun Aug 25 12:47:19 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flup/server/fcgi_base.py", line 601, in _end
[Sun Aug 25 12:47:19 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     sys.exit(appStatus)
[Sun Aug 25 12:47:19 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] SystemExit: 0
```

Edit_ter :

Ok, I just successfully launch testwsgi.py. I change my app function into application, and I add some lines at the end :

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
  from wsgiref.simple_server import make_server
  server = make_server('localhost', 8080, application)
  server.serve_forever()
```

I event don't know, why it's working, why it was not working before. ... And now I got some problem to open files, with their path (config files, or templates files ...)

```
[Sun Aug 25 13:10:51 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "/var/www/languageAnalyz/analyz.py", line 22, in getStats
[Sun Aug 25 13:10:51 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     flangs=open('config/languages.yml')
```

I try with absolute path, it didn't work too ...

Comment: You may also want to look at these questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17766595/403-forbidden-error-with-django-and-mod-wsgi/28394998#28394998 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3749331/django-with-mod-wsgi-returns-403-error

Answer (score 0):

You would appear to be following the wrong documentation for starters. For mod_wsgi use:

- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/

You appear to be using documentation for FASTCGI deployment.

Also, you cannot do:

```
import test-wsgi
```

A Python module name cannot have '-' in it.

In summary, go reread (or read) the Django documentation on deployment.

Comment: I even got more errors than before. I got the same error, and another one before this one.
I edit my post.

Comment: Ok, I just successfully launch testwsgi.py.
I change my app function into application, and I add some lines at the end : `if __name__ == '__main__':
    from wsgiref.simple_server import make_server
    server = make_server('localhost', 8080, application)
    server.serve_forever()`

I event don't know, why it's working, why it was not working before.
...

And now I got some problem to open files, with their path (config files, or templates files ...)

Comment: You cant use relative path names, you must use absolute path names. The current working directory will not be where you expect it to be. See http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ApplicationIssues#Application_Working_Directory

Comment: If you are using absolute path names, it may be a permissions issue. See http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ApplicationIssues#Access_Rights_Of_Apache_User

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem for a differnt file and making the file world executable fixed it for me. You would of course want to lock it down to the required user after you have narrowed this down as your issue:

```
chmod a+x test-wsgi.py
```

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was wsgi python version mismatch. I was using python 3, so:

```
$ sudo apt-get remove libapache2-mod-python libapache2-mod-wsgi
$ sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3
```