# Why is apache2 (2.2) not loading django (1.6.1)?

Tags: python, django, apache

Created a new django project with `/tmp$ django startproject testsite`

configured apache2 to run the application in /tmp/testsite/testsite/wsgi.py

Inside the wsgi.py there's a simple line `import django`  (this is everything at the moment, because i'm trying to debug).

I did configure the httpd.conf to run the wsgi file, which (i think) works, because the logs loog like this:

```
Wed Feb 26 16:55:07 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] mod_wsgi (pid=12621): Target WSGI script '/tmp/testsite/testsite/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Wed Feb 26 16:55:07 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] mod_wsgi (pid=12621): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/tmp/testsite/testsite/wsgi.py'.
[Wed Feb 26 16:55:07 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Wed Feb 26 16:55:07 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "/tmp/testsite/testsite/wsgi.py", line 26, in <module>
[Wed Feb 26 16:55:07 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     import django
[Wed Feb 26 16:55:07 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] ImportError: No module named django
```

I then checked if i have the required libraries on the sys.path, with a print - this showed that at the point of running the `import` statement, the sys.path was ok (In more detail, i had `/...../sistem-packages` in sys.path

Also looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18427766/apache2-and-mod-wsgi-target-wsgi-script-cannot-be-loaded-as-python-module) link and tried a `chmod a+x wsgi.py`, but the same error still appeared.

For reference, here are my files:

httpd.conf

```
WSGIScriptAlias /vwh /tmp/testsite/testsite/wsgi.py
WSGIPythonPath /tmp/testsite:/home/local/smth/user/ve/tmp1/lib/python2.7/site-packages

<Directory /tmp/testsite/testsite> 
<Files wsgi.py>
Order deny,allow
#Require all granted
Allow from all
</Files>
</Directory>
```

wsgi.py

```
import os
import sys
from subprocess import call

#print call(["which", "python"])     #also this gives a VERY weird result... prints `0`

import django
```

Also, tried printing the output of subprocess.call(['which','python']) but that has the weirdest result - returns `0` and i dont' know how to interpret it

**[EDIT]** I am the virtualenv what was installed at path `/home/local/smth/user/ve/tmp1`

**[EDIT]** Yes - i can import django from an interpreter, when the specified path is in the `sys.path`, and `django.__file__` returns `/home/local/smth/user/ve/tmp1/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.pyc`

Comment: On the `subprocess.call` thing--that's what it returns.  The return code of your process (typically 0 if the process returned sucessfully).  If you want it to output the stdout from that process you have to take additional steps.

Anyways, obvious question but is the full `django` package actually installed in `/home/local/smth/user/ve/tmp1/lib/python2.7/site-packages`?  Furthermore your mod_wsgi version might be relevant.

Comment: Does `import django` work in a Python shell in your virtual environment? If it does, what's in `django.__file__`?

Comment: @Iguananaut edited the answer. importing django works in the console.

Comment: @Iguananaut trying to find the version of mod_wsgi (installed today if that's relevant)... will edit the question when i find out the version

Comment: You wrote "`django.__file__` returns `/home/local/smth/user/ve/tmp1/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.pyc`".

But your `WSGIPythonPath` contains `/home/local/smth/user/ve/tmp1/lib/python2.7/site-packages`.  Note the missing `local/` in the path.

Comment: @Iguananaut thx for the remark, changed that so now the 2 paths are the same.... problem is it still doesn't work :|

Comment: What about other modules in your path?  Can they be imported?  Or is it just django?

Comment: @Iguananaut "i" can import them but "apache" can't. Meaning, i can do everything, with my user, but apache with its `www-data` user can read almost nothing. i solved the problem with giving others access. thx for helping!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing that did it was setting the proper access bits. 
Basically even though the proper site-packages was on in `sys.path`, the `www-data` user, for apache, didn't have privileges for reading or executing those files.

Moreover, since those files were in the home location for my user, i gave other users the ability to read and execute my home folder.

Now this is most likely a bad idea, and what you'd normally want to do is create a group of users, add the apache user to that group, and allow the users in that group to read and execute the files that one needs.